# Issue with mediawiki installation

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have recently up media wiki project in my localhost.when I trying to create a new user I got an error

```
Database error
A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the software.
Query:
SELECT 1 FROM `wiki_account_requests` WHERE acr_name = 'c' LIMIT 1
Function: UserAccountRequest::acquireUsername
Error: 1146 Table 'bourntec_wikinew.wiki_account_requests' doesn't exist (localhost)
```

how can I fix this error?

wiki version:1.22

Comment: Does the wiki_account_requests table actually exist in the database?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix no..it doesnt exist actulay..

Comment: The error comes from the [ConfirmAccount](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmAccount) extension which is apparently enabled but not set up properly. Maybe you just need to run `update.php`. (Out of curiosity, can I ask why you are using a five year old version of MediaWiki?)